# ionic - aguardar retorno de http get

Tags: ionic, angular, get, promises

Edit: solução na terceira resposta.

Estou tentando fazer uma função de login para um projeto no Ionic 2.
Essa função verifica se o usuário está cadastrado no banco de dados através do servidor php e retorna a id do usuário caso ele possua cadastro.
O meu problema é que como o método `http.get()` funciona de forma assíncrona, não consigo fazer a verificação se o retorno da função foi vazia, já que o resultado do retorno fica como undefined.
Tentei de duas formas, usando observable e promise:

> Com Observable:
>   função que chama o service:

```
    login() 
  {
    this.usuario = this.loginservice.get_usuario(this.loginusuario).subscribe(response =>this.usuario = response);
    console.log(this.usuario);
  }
```

> Codificação do service:

```
public get_usuario(usuario):Observable<any>
  {
      return this.http.get(this.urlusuario +"/"+ usuario.usuario +"/"+ 
   usuario.senha); 
  }
```

Dessa forma, na primeira vez que clico no botão que dispara a função login(), eu recebo como resposta o valor undefined. Na segunda vez que clico, ele retorna o valor da requisição anterior.

> Utilizando promise: Função que chama o service:

```
login() 
  {
    this.usuario = this.loginservice.get_usuario(this.loginusuario);
    console.log(this.usuario);
  }
```

> codificação do service:

```
public get_usuario(usuario):Promise<any>
  {
    var resultado;
      return this.http.get(this.urlusuario +"/"+ usuario.usuario +"/"+ usuario.senha).toPromise().then(function(data){
         return  data; 
      });
  }
```

Utilizando promise eu consigo o retorno do id na primeira execução da função login, porém não consegui encontrar nenhuma forma de acessar o __zone_symbol__value que é onde o objeto é armazenado segundo o `console.log()`.
[image: objeto console.log]

Queria saber se há uma forma de aguardar a resposta do `http.get()` para o programa continuar a execução (no caso de usar observable) ou como faço pra acessar o objeto que é retornado da promise

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para acessar o resultado de uma promise você pode fazer no service a requisição da seguinte forma:

```
public get_usuario(usuario):Promise<any> {
var resultado;
  return new Promise(resolve => { 
  this.http.get(this.urlusuario +"/"+ usuario.usuario +"/"+ usuario.senha)
  .subscribe( res => resolve(res));
 });
```

}

No método login capture os dados com:

```
 login() {
       this.loginservice.get_usuario(this.loginusuario).
       then(response => this.usuario = response);
        console.log(this.usuario);
  }
```

Tenho um exemplo trabalhando com promises no github. https://github.com/brognilucas/top-weather/blob/master/src/providers/city-service/city-service.ts

Comment: Utilizando os métodos que você postou, consegui acessar  o valor da promise, porém comecei a ter o mesmo erro do undefined quando eu disparo o evento login na primeira vez.

Comment: Ah... claro ... 
O console.log tem de estar dentro da promise, pois ele precisa esperar a resposta chegar para poder acessar, e o único logar que ele vai esperar é de fato dentro do .then ... 
O mesmo poderia ser feito direto com o subscribe, 
this.loginservice.get_usuario(this.loginusuario).subscribe(response =>  { 
this.usuario = response; 
   console.log(this.usuario);
});

fazendo deste jeito.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo. =]

Comment: Por nada, estamos ai para ajudar. :D

Answer (score 0):

Quero agradecer a sua ajuda Lucas, e contar como cheguei a solução final do meu problema.
Usei o código que você deu como resposta para pegar o valor de uma promise. Para esperar o retorno da requisição, adicionei `async` no nome da função login () e `await` na chamada do service.
O código ficou da seguinte forma:

> login()

```
async login() {
   await this.loginservice.get_usuario(this.loginusuario).
  then(response => this.usuario = response);
   console.log(this.usuario);
}
```

> get_usuario()

```
public get_usuario(usuario):Promise<any>
  {
      return this.http.get(this.urlusuario +"/"+ usuario.usuario +"/"+ usuario.senha).toPromise().then(function(data){
         return  data; 
      });
  }
```